# code in promise .then firing way before promise finishes

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, promise

I have this code...sorry for the messiness I've been at this a while:

```
loadAvailabilities() {

    let promises = [];
    let promises2 = [];
    let indexi = 0;
    //return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.appointments = this.af.list('/appointments', { query: {
        orderByChild: 'selected',
        limitToFirst: 10
      }});
      let mapped;
      this.subscription2 = this.appointments.subscribe(items => items.forEach(item => {
        //promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          console.log(item);
          let userName = item.$key;
          //this.availabilities = [];
          for(let x in item) {
            let month = x;
            console.log(x + "      month");

            this.appointmentsMonth = this.af.list('/appointments/' + userName + '/' + month);
            this.subscription3 = this.appointmentsMonth.subscribe(items => items.forEach(item => {
                this.startAtKeyAvail = item.$key;
                //console.log(JSON.stringify(item) + "           item");
                let date = new Date(item.date.day * 1000);
                let today = new Date();
                console.log(date.getMonth() + "==" + today.getMonth()  + "&&" + date.getDate() + "==" + today.getDate());
                console.log("IN LOAD AVAILABILITIES *(*((**(*(*(*(*(*(*&^^^^%^%556565656565");
                if(date.getMonth() == today.getMonth() && date.getDate() == today.getDate()) {
                  console.log("            inside the if that checks if its today");
                  console.log(item.reserved.appointment + "                *************appointment");
                  //let counter = 0;
                  //mapped = item.reserved.appointment.map((r) => {
                  //item.reserved.appointment.forEach((r, index) => {
                    for(let r of item.reserved.appointment) {
                      promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        if(r.selected == true) {
                          //this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.noavail.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');

                          let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('/settings/' + userName + '/profilepicture.png');

                          let obj = {'pic':"", 'salon': userName, 'time': r.time};

                          storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
                            console.log(url + "in download url !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                            obj.pic = url;
                            this.availabilities.push(obj);
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.availabilities));
                            resolve();
                          }).catch((e) => {
                            console.log("in caught url !!!!!!!$$$$$$$!!");
                            obj.pic = 'assets/blankprof.png';
                            this.availabilities.push(obj);
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.availabilities));
                            resolve();
                          });
                        }
                      }))

                  }

                }

               }))
             }
          }))
            //}));

          Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
            console.log("in load availabilities ......... ")
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.availabilities));

            this.availabilities.sort(function(a,b) {
              return Date.parse('01/01/2013 '+a.time) - Date.parse('01/01/2013 '+b.time);
            });

            console.log('*****previous******');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.availabilities));
            console.log('*****sorted********');

            for(let i of this.availabilities) {
              console.log(i.time + "          this is itime");
              let date = new Date('01/01/2013 ' + i.time);
              console.log(date + "          this is date in idate");
              let str = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', hour12: true, minute: 'numeric' });
              console.log(str);
              i.time = str;
            }
          });
      //}))



    //})

  }
```

I can tell from the log messages that the `storageRef.getDownloadURL()` function happens close to the end of when my page loads...this is where the objects actually get pushed to `this.availabilities` (eventually used to populate a list). The code in the `Promise.all` `.then()` actually fires before anything gets pushed to `this.availabilities` so when the sorting happens it is an empty array and nothing gets sorted.

Comment: Instead of apologizing for the messiness of this wall of code. Throw it away, start over. Anyone who would seriously answer would have to do the same, so it would be decent of you to start. I'd be seriously surprised if more than 10% of what you have posted contributed to your issue. Throwing out the other 90% would help both us and you in pinning it down.

Comment: yah i guess i should just start over with this...i guess im wondering about the `forEach` loops inside eachother..and the promise inside that...and what is going on async and what is going on sync....but yah im gonna start anew...this is code that i wrote early on and things have changed

Comment: General tip. Unnest your code. Write dedicated functions for every single meaningful step. Start with factoring out the innermost stuff. Ideally stay under four lines of code per function. Work with map() and reduce(). Chain your promises. Lean towards running one map() more than one fewer. Loop performance is not your issue in an async situation anyway, so dont't optimize for it. Optimize for flat, obvious code.

Comment: cool thanks for the advice...i decided to try one more thing before scrapping the code and it worked. i do agree this code needs to be refactored...sadly the whole project is kind of like this do to poor project management leaving no time to meet deadlines

Comment: Refactor it for the learning effect. Learning is more effective with real-world scenarios (especially those you are already familiar with) and real-world scenarios are more effective than textbook examples. You can't get much better conditions, IMHO. (I'm deliberately staying vague, I'm on mobile currently and couldn't refactor your code anyway right now. I just recognize that the spaghetti threshold has been passed and refactoring is due.)

Answer (score 0):

I used a promise inside each `forEach` loop. I pushed all the promises to the same `array` and used `Promise.all(array).then(...)` how it is being used above - and the promises did their job - the array is sorted because everything is happening asynchronously.

Comment: Presumably the `.subscribe()` method acts as an asynchronous `.get()` rather than a true "subscribe". Otherwise, it's hard to see that the above approach, even after tidying/fixing, would ever work.